# Is there a lifecycle hook that runs once after a components initialisation, but also after two-way-binding is loaded?

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am trying to select some text in an input field after a component is initialised. I know I can do this with a `setTimeout()`, but that feels a bit too hacky.

Most hooks run before the input text is loaded by two-way binding. The others also run every time someone selects the other field.

**The code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxrssq**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <input #input type="text" [(ngModel)]="info.one"/>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="info.two"/>`,
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() info;
  @ViewChild('input', {static: true} ) input;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.input.nativeElement.select();
  }

}
```

Is there a lifecycle hook that runs once after a components initialisation, but after two-way-binding is loaded?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Nope, I tried `AfterViewInit`. It should select the text, it doesn't ( so that loads before the two-way binding is completed ). https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hsqvrq

Answer (score 5):

as a matter of fact, using `setTimeout()` is not *a hacky solution* it is **the** solution. because of [angular's unidirectional data flow rule](https://angular.io/guide/glossary#unidirectional-data-flow).

> Angular's unidirectional data flow rule forbids updates to the view after it has been composed.

in order to observe consequences of this rule, try assigning a new value to `info` property of `ChildComponent` on `AfterViewInit` hook. you'll get an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` which is angular's way of saying that "updates to the view after it has been composed is forbidden!"

since you are not updating any of your component's data-bound properties and just making dom manipulation, angular is not throwing any error but it is not reflecting your changes to dom as well.

coming back to your question;

> Is there a lifecycle hook that runs once after a components initialisation, but after two-way-binding is loaded?

yes there is and it is [AfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) hook. Because;

> View queries are set before the ngAfterViewInit callback is called.

and DOM updates are handled before `ngAfterViewInit` is called as explained in [here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error).

and it comes [after](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#sequence-and-frequency-of-all-lifecycle-events) [OnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) hook, where;

> OnChanges is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes.

consequently you should do as follows if you want the text get selected just once when the first time component is loaded.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => this.input.nativeElement.select());
}
```

if you want to select text whenever `input` property gets changed by parent component (including first load) then you need to implement `OnChanges` hook.

```js
ngOnChanges() {
  setTimeout(() => this.input.nativeElement.select());
}
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owahps

hope it helps.